# Check if mock setup returns string type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to be able to check if mocked method returns a string type NOT a specific string. So far I have got:

```
this.mockFoo.Setup(k => k.FooMethod(It.Is<string>(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s).Equals(false))));
```

I know that there is a `Returns()` method available after `Setup`. However, It seems like, it wants to know a specific value to return. The point is I don't want to provide specific value because it is not a case in the test.

How Can I achieve that?

Comment: What's the return type of `FooMethod` ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to test BarMethod that calls FooMethod internally? And the test should be green if BarMethod passes any (not empty) string to FooMethod?

Comment: @Spotted return type of `FooMethod` is Task<string>. I tried sth: `.Returns(() => Task.FromResult<string>("specificValue"))` But it ask for specific value to return.

Comment: @Georg Patscheider I don't have `BarMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what a Mock is used for. A Mock is Setup to do specific things, but when you want to know if a function call returned a specific type, you have to execute the function call on the type of interest.

Comment: **if a function call returned a specific type, you have to execute the function call on the type of interest.** @Bernhard Hiller Could you provide an example ?